# What's this device that is attached to the hot shoe?

Tags: hotshoe

In this youtube video (High-Tech Photography of Nature in Japan), at [this](https://youtu.be/tkDjvOygdGc?t=77) point, what is that device attached to that photographer's camera?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It is a dot sight that is intended for use with a rifle, and has been adapted for use with a camera. They are useful for finding (and tracking) elusive subjects without having to look through a telephoto lens. Dot sights designed for use with cameras are available, as the following YouTube video shows:

[Olympus EE-1 Dot Sight Review with the M.Zuiko 300mm f/4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnTAbBSUHZk)

Comment: AH! I somewhat guessed it would be one of those.. (I search about bridge cameras a lot and I found that the Olympus SP100 has one).... But why it is red when looked from the front?; and only from front. Can't it be *coupled* with a zoom lens?; when the lens is zoomed, the dot sight's reticle is also changes..?

Comment: I've never used one. In fact, I didn't even know that they existed. The idea is that they give you a reasonably wide field of view, so that you can track a moving object -- something that is very difficult to do with a telephoto lens. I don't see any need for one to be coupled to a zoom lens.

Comment: "I don't see any need for one to be coupled to a zoom lens"  So you say that once set, the reticle's placement is correct for lenses of all focal lengths?

Comment: If you watch the video, you will see that it needs to be adjusted for each lens that you use. If you are using a zoom lens, it recommends that you adjust it for the longest focal length. If I had one (and getting one is tempting), I would make sure that it was correctly adjusted every time that I used it.

Comment: Ok yes, I heard that one, then, once set for a particular lens, is the reticle's placement correct for wider focal lengths?

Comment: If it is accurately aligned with the axis of the lens mount, it should be aligned with any (straight-through) lens that you fit. You will achieve the most accurate alignment if you first set it up with a long-focal length lens. However, there is always the risk of knocking it when changing a lens, so I would check the alignment with every lens change.

Comment: So, the reason to the reticle's placement is not suitable for every lens, is different lenses's misalignment,..right?

Comment: It is the same concept as a Telescope. They have a low resolution telescope included, to make a general search, then you look details on the large one.

Comment: @Rafael you mean the finderscope? (is **it** the name?)

Comment: The misalignment is independent on the lens, if it is straight, obviously. It depends on the distance between the camera and the object, the distance between lens' axis and the dot sight and angle you are looking through it.

Comment: You'd get parallax error, the amount depending on focal length and distance to subject. At any reasonable distance (for wildlife, sports, etc) it usually won't matter. Don't use it for macro work though :-).

Comment: I think @Rafael meant astronomical telescope.

Comment: @user152435 In conjunction with lenses, I expect you would 'zero', the same concept as with a firearm, everytime you change lens, take it on/off this is to ensure that the sight matches point of aim. To do this, you would get your lense point it at a static point, e.g. street sign the distance of the subject, you would then use what looks like an allen key to adjust elevation and windage of the sight (up-down and left-right ). Luckily unlike a bullet, you don't have to worry about actual wind and elevation. So once it's zeroed, should be good to go.